# Where to start in building a chrome extension

Tags: browser, google-chrome-extension

Im looking to get more into programming, and I've decided to look into creating a browser extension. This is exactly the kind of project I've been looking for to get stuck into programming web stuff but I'm new to it so I don't know where to start.

Could anyone suggest the different things I should look into?

The only programming experience I have so far is in Matlab. I've looked into C on and off in the past I but I have no practical experience with it.

I've started to have a look at Twando, an open source program which schedules tweets on Twitter where I'm going through and understanding all the code for that program (mostly php).

Afterwards I'll look more carefully at how to write Chrome browser extensions and then probably look into how to make 3rd party programs work with Twitter, Pinterest etc.

Am I looking along the right lines? Any constructive criticism will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do this using Javascript (and maybe JQuery, which is a library for Javascript that makes it easier/adds alot of easy to use functions).

For the basics: 
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

This is great for learing to work with JSON and chrome extensions:
http://lifehacker.com/5857721/how-to-build-a-chrome-extension

What you could also do is download a simple extension from the "store" and open it to check what's inside. This helped me the most with learning Javascript and JQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll definitely go through that LH article once I've finished looking through this source code. I'll then look at the code of similar extensions.